# Raspberry Pi camera. Out of resources

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, tornado

Trying to launch my camera with motion sensor.
Works fine like this:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import picamera
import datetime
import os

def getFileName():
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S.h264")

pin = 4
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
prevState = False
currState = False
camera = picamera.PiCamera()
while True:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    prevState = currState
    currState = GPIO.input(pin)
    if currState != prevState:
        newState = "HIGH" if currState else "LOW"
        print ("GPIO pin %s is %s" % (pin, newState))
        if currState:
            fileName = getFileName()
            print ("Starting Recording...")
            camera.start_preview()
            camera.start_recording(fileName)
            time.sleep(10)
            print (fileName)
        else:
            camera.stop_preview()
            time.sleep(1)
            camera.stop_recording()
            print ("Stopped Recording")

    else:
        print("No motions")
```

But then i try to def my function for Tornado server:

```
def secure_on(prevState, currState):
    pin = 4
    #GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    #GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
    #camera = picamera.PiCamera()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    prevState = currState
    #currState = GPIO.input(pin)
    if currState != prevState:
        newState = "HIGH" if currState else "LOW"
        return {'info': "GPIO pin %s is %s" % (pin, newState)}
        if currState:
            fileName = getFileName()
            print ("Starting Recording...")
            #camera.start_preview()
            #camera.start_recording(fileName)
            time.sleep(10)
            return {'info': fileName}
        else:
            #camera.stop_preview()
            time.sleep(1)
            #camera.stop_recording()
            return {'info': "Stopped Recording"}
    else:
        return {'info': "No motions"}
```

Tornado:

```
class SecureOnHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        result = RosPi.secure_on(prevSec, currSec)

        self.write({"info": result['info']})
```

After that i get an error

> "Camera component couldn't be enabled: Out of resources (other than memory)
>   ERROR:tornado.access:500 GET /secure_on

What could be causing the error?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/26829/picamera-not-working)

Comment: He had a broken camera. But mine is running correctly with simple Python code and does whatever it has to. It doesn't run, when i add camera module to Tornado server

Comment: @Alexzz *"So it turns out that Camera port of my Raspberry Pi had some problem. Replaced the Pi, camera is working smoothly."* - Coderaemon. I'm not saying you should throw away your Pi, but simply that it was the Pi and not the camera that was broken

Comment: If i had a problem with Pi it won't work in any case (including running Python file with first part of the code in thread). But mine does

Comment: True true. I never thought your Pi was broken - I just corrected you. I posted the link because it had a few good observations. E.g. *"(...) the cause for this error could also be that another process is currently using the camera."*. Maybe the error is somehow related to Tornado being an asynchronous, non-blocking framework

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question but I just wanted to post my solution to the `Out of resources` error in case it can save someone time and effort.

The problem for me was that I was initializing the camera module is two Python files at the same time (a script with a while loop that took a picture when motion was detected and another script that took a picture on demand).

As per the documentation: https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/faq.html#camera-locks-up-with-multiprocessing you must ensure that only a single process creates an instance of `PiCamera` at one time.

My solution was simply to move initializing the camera module inside a function and call `.close()` after taking the picture to free up the process ready to be used by the next script that calls it.

Comment: I did same configuration error and this answer gave me good hint what I had done wrong.